# Using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

This is my **Messages Model**, this table has two Foreign Keys **id_from** and **id_to**, both from the User table. How can I establish this by using eloquent in Laravel?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Messages extends Model
{


    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','id_from');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','id_to');
    }

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $fillable = ['id_to','id_from','message'];
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: Surely not using the same function name. Just rename the second one? `public function userFrom(){}` and `public function userTo(){}` will be fine

Comment: you are using duplicate method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tow diferent functions for that :

```
public function userFrom(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','id_from');
}

public function userTo(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','id','id_to');
}
```

And one more thing is that the name of the function **must** be in `camelCase`